# Find the maximum in a string

Tags: c++, c, string

Given an array of strings, I have to find the maximum (in lexicographical sense) in each string, and make a string out of this. 
I've come out with this function:

```
void get_max_string(sa str_arr, int dim, string max_car) {

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<dim; i++) {

        for(j = 0 ; j+1 < strlen(str_arr[i]) ; j++) {

            if (str_arr[i][j] > str_arr[i][j+1])

                max_car[i] = str_arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

"sa" is a string array, "string" is obviously a characters array.

The problem is that it seems to ignore the first character.
What's the error?

Comment: Do you know `strcmp/strcmpi` function?

Comment: why `if (str_arr[i][j] > str_arr[i][j+1])`? when you want to find the max value you need to compare to the current maximum

Comment: This looks like a pure C question. Why the `c++` tag?

Comment: Well the exercise is for a course in which we use both C and C++, so it doesn't matter which language I pick to solve it

Comment: Why don't you put the **exact definition** of "sa"?  is it defined as `string[N]`? is it defined as `*string`? is it defined as `vector<string>`, or is it defined as `char *str_arr[]` ???  as it has been pointed out, there's a **strcmp(3)**. Do you know that strings can be compared with `>` operator? does it ignore the first or the last character? you cannot use **strlen(3)** with a `string` (you have to convert it to a `char *` first, passing over it twice (once to convert to `char *` and another to calculate its length)  Why do you mix `char *` with `string` ????  use one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution and I try to make use of your code. The problem of your code is you don't assign `max_arr[i]` to an initial value .

```
void get_max_string(sa str_arr, int dim, string max_car) {

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<dim; i++) {
        max_car[i] = str_arr[i][0]; //init max_car[i] with the first letter

        for(j = 0 ; j + 1< strlen(str_arr[i]) ; j++) { 

            if (max_car[i] < str_arr[i][j+1])

                max_car[i] = str_arr[i][j+1]; // find a larger value
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this c++ I would use c++. E.g like this(not tested)

```
string get_max_string(const vector<string>& sa) {
    string res;
    for_each(begin(sa), end(sa), [&res](const string& s){
        res.push_back(*max_element(s.begin(), s.end()));
    });
    return res;
}
```